# Java Cucumber - Junit "Could not find class" in command line

Tags: java, command-line, junit, cucumber, automated-tests

Trying to do some automated tests. I am getting an error when I try to execute junit in command line,

**Commands tried**

```
java -cp C:/Users/path/Downloads/selenium-java-3.0.1/lib/junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore C:/Users/path/workspace/CucumberConcept/src/ cucumber.CucumberRunner

java -cp C:/Users/path/Downloads/selenium-java-3.0.1/lib/junit-4.12.jar;C:/Users/path/workspace/CucumberConcept/src/ org.junit.runner.JUnitCore cucumber.CucumberRunner

java -cp C:/Users/path/Downloads/selenium-java-3.0.1/lib/junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CucumberConcept.src.cucumber.CucumberRunner

java -cp C:/Users/path/Downloads/selenium-java-3.0.1/lib/junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore cucumber.CucumberRunner.CucumberRunner

java -cp C:/Users/path/Downloads/selenium-java-3.0.1/lib/junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CucumberRunner.CucumberRunner

java -cp C:/Users/path/Downloads/selenium-java-3.0.1/lib/junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CucumberRunner CucumberRunner

java -cp C:/Users/path/Downloads/selenium-java-3.0.1/lib/junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CucumberRunner.java CucumberRunner

java -cp C:/Users/path/Downloads/selenium-java-3.0.1/lib/junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CucumberRunner
```

**Junit code:**

```
package cucumber;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.junit.*;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty","json:target/json/output.json","html:target/html/"},
        features = {"src/cucumber/"}
        )
public class CucumberRunner {
}
```

**Command line**

C:\Users\path\CucumberConcept\src>java -classpath C:/Users/path/lib/junit-4.12.jar;classes org.junit.runner.JUnitCore cucumber.CucumberRunner

```
JUnit version 4.12
.E
Time: 0.004
There was 1 failure:
1) initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [cucumber.CucumberRunne
r]
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCom
mandLineParseResult.java:102)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseArgs(JUnitCommandLi
neParseResult.java:50)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(JUnitCommandLinePa
rseResult.java:44)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.CucumberRunner
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:16)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCom
mandLineParseResult.java:100)
        ... 4 more

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath is broken.

Are you able to use a build tool like Maven? It may be a lot easier than to construct your classpath by hand.

Clone or download the Java skeleton provided by the Cucumber team and see if you can get it to run. It can be found here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

If you are not able to use Maven, Ant or Gradle then look in the `build.xml` to get some inspiration on how to build you classpath manually.